# Android start activity when bluetooth start

Tags: android, bluetooth

Hi guys I am studying in app. How can I create a program When I open bluetooth it will show a dialog and two button if I click yes will open activity

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use broadcast receiver that will  fire action when Bluetooth open , start the dialog